# Как связать таблицы при seeding laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8, factory

есть модель Product и Category.
product table has field category_id.
как сделать так чтобы при seeding каждая новая категория принадлежала 3 и 4 продуктам ?
например : Продукт № 1,2,3 под категорией например 1, продукт № 2 под категорией 4,5,6....

Я могу создать через laravel factory продукт 1 has category 1.  Но мне нужно чтобы по категорией было несколько продуктов .

Вопрос в том как корректно написать фабрику ....